# How can i use operators `new` and `delete` within shared memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-memory

I want to share some objects between multiple programs using shared memory.

I've found example at [this site](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8461). It doesn't have any allocation of object, just direct addressing, but i want to create struct or class in shared memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the memory is already allocated you want to use **placement new**:

```
void * ptr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
// Handle errors
MyClass * x = new (ptr) MyClass;
```

Then, the new instance of `MyClass` will be constructed in memory pointed by `ptr`.

When the object is not needed, you have to manually call the destructor (without freeing the memory).

```
ptr->MyClass::~MyClass();
```

Answer (score 7):

An object can be created in any suitable aligned storage using placement new:

```
void* storage = get_aligned_shared_memory();
T* object = new (storage) T();
```

That said — have you considered using a library such as [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess.html) for this.

Comment: Thank's for that library, it's library i've been looking for :)